# Visual Studio Support (DDEX) for PostgreSQL with Entity Framework - Where is the setup file? (.exe)

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

I wanted to start using PostgreSQL with Entity Framework, so I went to 
[Visual Studio Support (DDEX)](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html) page, which says:

> Grab the latest setup program (.exe-file) from https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases and run it.

I went to that page, but I can't find the .exe installation file anywhere.
Where do I find the installation for DDEX tools?

P.S. There might be a possibility that the file was in front of my nose but I didn't see it. In that case feel free to down-vote me, but please leave the answer with the location/instructions where I can find the file :)

Comment: We're currently working out some issues with the DDEX provider so it's not yet available for Npgsql 3.x. However, note that you do not need the DDEX provider for code-first EF6.

Comment: I'd like to do DB first. I don't necessarily need EDMX model, but I need a way to generate code out of my DB after every change in the DB schema. Is there a tool for that, like T4 template or similar?

Comment: I'm not sure if EF6 database-first supports *incremental* changes to your code model based on database schema changes (it could be, I'm just a code-first person)... Try to search whether this is possible with EF6 and SqlServer (thus removing PostgreSQL/Npgsql from the equation), that'll point you in the right direction...

Comment: @ShayRojansky I tried with code-first, but in MonoDevelop - no success. Problem is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917924/postgresql-with-entityframework-in-monodevelop-on-ubuntu). Does Npgsql 3.x work on Mono? Would you be able to provide a sample app.config file which is working on Mono? I'd really like to use PostgreSQL for this project, but I'm stuck on this since yesterday. Thanks a lot in advance Shay!

Answer (score 2):

I used for it version 2.2.5 and this version contains "setup program (.exe-file)". See there: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/tag/v2.2.5
I spent a lot of time to find this simple way.