# PostgreSQL with EntityFramework in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu

Tags: entity-framework, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, npgsql

I tried to configure a project in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu, to use EntityFramework with Npgsql provider, by following [official steps](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ef6.html).

However, something seem to be wrong with that suggested configuration file (or I'm missing something), as I can't get rid of this error:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkLegacy, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Does anyone have a simple working example of the application connecting to PostgreSQL using Entity Framework in MonoDevelop?

Comment: Can you please try with Npgsql 3.0.3 (the error says 2.1.0)? The correct package for this would be EntityFramework6.Npgsql, not Npgsql.EntityFrameworkLegacy

Comment: @ShayRojansky Yay! :) Thanks a lot Shay! I was blind :) Could you enter the answer below so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with Npgsql 3.0.3 (the error says 2.1.0), the correct package for this would be EntityFramework6.Npgsql, not Npgsql.EntityFrameworkLegacy.